# Linux Bash Scripting execute SSH remote commands

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a strange problem by running commands remote via ssh from a linux shell script an no solution for this!

These commands are:

```
rpm -qa | grep bzd* | sort
rpm -qa | grep bzd-eet
rpm -qa | grep bzd-five
```

All these commands running fine, if I use them on shell prompt on the remote machine. If these commands are loaded from a textfile into an array it is still working:

```
while read line
do
   commands+=("$line")
done < commands.txt

ssh root@server "${commands[0]}"   
ssh root@server "${commands[1]}"
ssh root@server "${commands[2]}"

echo ${commands[0]} output -->rpm -qa | grep bzd* | sort       
echo ${commands[1]} output -->rpm -qa | grep bzd-eet 
echo ${commands[2]} output -->rpm -qa | grep bzd-five
```

--> The ssh commands deliver correct packages that should be found on remote machines in that case.

Problem:

If i store the output of these commands in a variable it is NOT working anymore!!!

example:

```
results=$(ssh root@server "${commands[0]}")
echo "${results[@]} --> output: nothing

results=$(ssh root@server "${commands[1]}")
echo "${results[@]} --> output: nothing  

results=$(ssh root@server "${commands[2]}")
echo "${results[@]} --> output: nothing
```

BUT

```
results=$(ssh root@server rpm -qa | grep bzd* | sort)
echo "${results[@]} --> output: correct output!!!!!!
```

What is going on here? It seems that commands loaded from any sort of array are not properly executed in ssh connection. What can I do?

Comment: I can't actually reproduce the problem, everything seems to check out. Are you sure this is a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Is there any reason to store these commands in an array variable? Just running `ssh` from within the `read` loop would seem simpler and more straightforward. Or even better, `ssh root@server <commands.txt`

Comment: Couple comments. Like "emmrk" I get a result. Also since you are trying to access all items in results array, I suspect you wanted to say `results=($(ssh root@server "${commands[0]}"))` instead to assign to `results` as an array.